# Required request part 'file' is not present. Trying upload an image, angular -> spring

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest, multipart

I have my endpoint in spring-boot API for uploading images. It's working fine with the postman, but if I want to send a request from my angular app I'm getting code 400 "Required request part 'file' is not present".

I think the problem is in my angular code.

My endpoint

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/private/image/avatar", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public BasicImgurResponse uploadProfilePicture(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file){
    try {
        return service.uploadProfilePicture(file);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImgurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My angular service method

```java
uploadAvatar(data: any){
    let file = new FormData();
    file.append('file',data);
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.api_endpoint+'/private/image/avatar',file);
}
```

[image: headers]

[image: params]

Comment: Similar problem. Fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

May be data object is empty? Make sure that data object contains a input file.

Without Angular, the command will be as below:

```
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: Its not empty, i can see params in devtools.

Comment: Could you use firebug or chrome development tool to view the request sent by angular?